# NetworkImage in flutter - expired token

Tags: dart, flutter

I am creating a network image provider like so:

```
ImageProvider image = NetworkImage(
          url,
          headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken});
```

But the accessToken will expire at a certain point.  How do I refresh the token in this case, where I display the image in a totally different place from where I create the request?

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use custom HttpClient to implement the token refresh behind the scenes. HttpClient is used internally by NetworkImage, so if you "override" the client, NetworkImage will pick it up automatically. Code is taken from [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpOverrides-class.html)

```
class MyHttpClient implements HttpClient {
  ...
  // An implementation of the HttpClient interface
  ...
}

main() {
  HttpOverrides.runZoned(() {
    ...
    // Operations will use MyHttpClient instead of the real HttpClient
    // implementation whenever HttpClient is used.
    ...
  }, createHttpClient: (SecurityContext c) => new MyHttpClient(c));
}
```